# Android facebook Action intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm curious what happens when you create an Intent chooser and the user doesn't have any apps that can do what you're specifying. 
For example if I try to open up a facebook profile via an Intent and the user has neither the facebook app or any browser on their phone.

How would you check to see if the user has an app to open your Intent with before they actually open it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the help of PackageManager

```
    final PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if(list.size() > 0)
    // there is some app that will handle this intent
    else
    // there is no app to handle this intent
```

`queryIntentActivities` look for the activities that have registered for the intent you are querying and return the number of activities that can handle that intent.
You can find detailed discussion on this link http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html